# Downloading via boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am using boto client to download and upload my files to s3 and do a whole bunch of other things like copy from one folder key to another and etc. The problem arises when I try to copy a key whose size is 0 bytes. The code that I use to copy is below

```
# Get the connection to the bucket
conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_KEY, SECRET_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket('mybucket')

# bucket.name is the name of my bucket
# candidate is the source key
destination_key = "destination/path/on/s3"
candidate = "the/file/to/copy"

# now copy the key
bucket.copy_key(destination_key, bucket.name, candidate) # --> This throws an exception

# just in case, see if the key ended up in the destination. 
copied_key = bucket.lookup(destination_key)
```

The exception that I get is

```
3ResponseError: 404 Not Found
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
     <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
     <Key>the/file/to/copy</Key><RequestId>ABC123</RequestId><HostId>XYZ123</HostId>
</Error>
```

Now I have verified that the key infact exists by logging into the aws console and navigating to the source key location, the key is there and the aws console shows that its size is 0 (there are cases in my application that I may end up with empty files but I need them on s3).

So upload works fine, boto uploads the key without any issue, but when I attempt to copy it, then I get the error that the key does not exist

So is there any other logic that I should be using to copy such keys? Any help in this regard would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the bucket of the source key. Should be something like `bucket/path/to/file/to/copy`

Comment: Thanks for the response, Yes I have already done that at the time of establishing the connection. Edited my answer to show how I established connection

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from boto.s3.key import Key
download_path = '/tmp/dest_test.jpg'
bucket_key = Key(bucket)
bucket_key.key = file_key # e.g. images/source_test.jpg
bucket_key.get_contents_to_filename(download_path)
```